# grep function in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a vector called ew12 which looks like this

```
2|7;27;0.878,0.888;
```

I seperated it using the scan command and ; as sep. What I then get is

```
ew12
[1] "2|7"      "27"       "0.878,0.888"
```

I then want to grep the "2|7" pattern and use

```
grep("^2|7$", ew12)
```

which results in 
    [1] 1 2 3

but the pattern is not present in all three elements..

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match the exact string, you have to use double escapes for the bar, i.e., `\\|`:

```
grep("^2\\|7$", ew12)
[1] 1
```

You can also use

```
which(ew12 == "2|7")
[1] 1
```

Comment: which text did you get this from..is the | an exception?

Comment: @user3069326 The character `|` means logical *or* in regular expressions. If you want a literal interpretation you have to use two escapes, `\\|`. I learned this at stackoverflow.com.

Comment: You could also use the `fixed = TRUE` argument to `grep` and avoid the escapes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the parenthesis(If i am getting your question correctly).

Try : `grep("^(2|7)$",ew12)`

Comment: but theni GET INTEGER8=9 AS RESULT::IS THE ASCI OF THE | MAYBE OF IMPORTANCE?

Comment: can you restructure your sentence, please? i am not getting what you want to convey?

Comment: oh..ups..I just get integer(0) as a result if I do this. I was wondering maybe the asci of pipi in my data and pipe i use on the keyboard are different?

Comment: @user3069326 This regular expression returns `integer(0)` because there is no string of length one in your character vector. This command matches two strings, `"2"` and `"7"`.

Comment: you can also use stringr package to do this job its my personal suggestion and its better than grep, library(stringr) ;str_extract(ew12,"^(2|7)$"). but then i don't know what do you want as an outcome, if you want something which has "2" or "7" , the above will work, but if you want to match pipes as well then below solution of Mr. Hohenstein is good.